# Why is the maximum principle not valid here?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

> Why is the maximum principle not valid here ?

$u:\mathbf R^n_{+}\times (0,1]$ and $u(x,t)=1-\frac{1}{\left(4\pi (t-1/2)\right)^{n/2}}e^{\frac{-|x+1|^2}{4t-2}}$ then $u$ is bounded by $1$ and satisfies $u_t-\Delta u=0$, for example $u(x,1/2)=1$ in the interior but $u$ is not constant

Why does the maximum principle not hold ?

EDIT: I have the solution here, but it is not mentioned where the maximum principle fails

[image]

Comment: How are you getting $u(x,1/2)=1$ in the interior?

Comment: @Ian Sorry I think I have it correct now. If $\Phi$ is the heat kernel then $\Phi(x+1,t-1/2)$ should be as above, am I still wrong ?

Comment: Now $t=1/2$ makes no sense...

Comment: Look at the denominator of the heat kernel part. If you indeed wanted it to be a time shift then you need to divide by $(t - 1/2)^{n/2}$.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong you mean the exponential part is correct and the fraction should be raplaced by $\frac{1}{(4\pi (t-1/2))^{n/2}}$

Comment: @halvet Correct. The bottom line is that for your function to be harmonic, it better be a shift of the heat kernel, in which case it is not bounded.

Comment: If you shift the time back by 1/2, you would be asking for the maximum principle to hold in the time period $[-1/2,1/2]$, when usually it only holds for $t \geq 0$.  Of course this makes intuitive sense:  For $t < 0$ the heat equation is going "backwards":  hot things get hotter rather than heat dissipating, and peak temperature can be reached at $t=0$.

Comment: @halvet OK, using your updated question (to which my comments are no longer wholly relevant), you should pay attention to the behavior of the function $\Phi$ that is defined; in particular, they do something unusual for $\Phi(\cdot, t)$ when $t < 0$. Then consider all the hypotheses of the maximum principle.